# logically centralized but physically decentralized contract

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, contract-deployment, blocks

Reading https://uport.me/library/pdf/whitepaper.pdf it states :

```
The uPort Registry Contract acts as a logically centralized but physically decentralized registry or lookup
table mapping each uPort identitifier to an IPFS hash linking to a structure containing the user’s attributes,
profile data and attestations (see below for more information on attestations).
```

From this statement are my interpretation correct :

The Registry contract is physically decentralized as it exists all ethereum mining node within their blockchain ?

The Registry contract is logically centralized as all logic is contained within a centralized location ?

Comment: Doesn't that apply for many smart-contract based services?

Answer (score 1):

No centralized location.

I would interpret as logically centralized in the sense that there's one logical address space entrusted with the info. Very different from logically de-centralized profiles stored separately in places like twitter, facebook, domain controllers, stackexchange, et al.